# which quitclaim deed do I need?

Tags: united-states, new-jersey, claims, real-property, name-title

The owner of the house is deceased, and still has mortgage to pay.
The wife would like to take over the home, and pay for it whole.

With this circumstance, which quitclaim deed is needed?

Answer (score 1):

You need a lawyer.

What happens to the house, and what steps are necessary to make the wife the sole owner, depend on several complicated factors. It's unlikely that a quit claim deed will play any part in the process.